# in chrome bootstrap affix add website name

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

in affix i add a website name, the name is hidden. when scroll down the website name show, and scroll up name will be hidden.
i use jquery for this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || >document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
            $(".brand_name").removeClass("hidden");   
        } else {
            $(".brand_name").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

and code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default clearfix" data-spy="affix" data-    offset-top="197">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand brand_name hidden" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Sports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Attraction</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Events <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
```

in mozilla working good...but problem in chrome.
how to solve this....please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scrollTop()` instead of `scrollTop`.

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

`scrollTop` seems to be accepted in Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to make things work:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default clearfix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand brand_name" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Sports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Attraction</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Events <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>    


 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, architecto eum sapiente dolorem nostrum saepe! Voluptas deserunt aperiam eligendi tempora sit incidunt similique ab. Sequi, earum qui blanditiis officiis magni?</p>
```

JS:

```
var scrollvalue=$(window).scrollTop();

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()>scrollvalue)
    {
      $(".navbar-header a").removeClass('hidden');
      scrollvalue=$(window).scrollTop();
    }
  else
    {
      $(".navbar-header a").addClass('hidden');
      scrollvalue=$(window).scrollTop();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/SkyT/Lf1sr34y/1/